# Creating "OmniFocus Clippings" support for Thunderbird on Mac OS X: what tools and documentation references needed?

Tags: c++, macos, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I want to add [OmniFocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus/) [Clippings](http://goo.gl/YAVTY) support to [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) running on Mac OS X (10.6 and above).  Presuming it doesn't already exist (I can't get it to work--no references on the web to it working), what tools/references do I need to complete the job?  I can download and build TB ok; the pre-existing guides on how to make TB add-ons/extensions will help me there; it's the "Mac OS X Services programming" (or whatever is required to get TB to "talk" to OmniFocus via the "OmniFocus: Send to Inbox" **service**; see this [screenshot](http://i40.tinypic.com/352n9lu.png)) that I don't know how to manage.  If possible, pls also include pointers to where in the TB code base I need to update.

Ultimately, I understand a "Thunderbird" entry must be shown via the OmniFocus [Clippings preference dialogue window](http://i43.tinypic.com/2wf4soz.png)...?

I've logged a TB ["bug"](http://goo.gl/BaK6f) plus started a [discussion](http://goo.gl/KXjhp) at OmniFocus forums.

I want to update my installed TB instance as quickly as possible.  I'm happy to simply hack a downloaded src code branch (from TB's mercurial or whatever) and re-apply a patch for each TB version upgrade... assuming this feature add is not cumbersome.  I don't yet have any aspirations to [create a full-fledged TB extension/add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Thunderbird/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension).

fwiw. I was once a professional software developer (C, C++, Java, Python and several other languages mostly on Unix/Linux, including "large system integration" projects) and am now mostly just a "business person," but I re-pickup coding if/as need be for special projects.  Which I'm considering doing now.

Answer (score 0):

For now I use http://www.omnigroup.com/support/omnifocus-mail-drop as a work around, but Omnifocus Clippings support for Thunderbird would be highly appreciated as it is more efficient :)